# drupal mod_rewrite not working

Tags: drupal, mod-rewrite, centos5

I have a problem with drupal in Clean Url Module. In my apache conf I have:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
Uncomment.

When I run #/usr/sbin/httpd -M
I get the module:

rewrite_module (shared)

But in drupal I can't see (e.g) localhost/mydrupalpath/page (404), instead I need put "?q=" for get a result: localhost/mydrupalpath/?q=page.

In .htaccess too I have a correct configuration:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

My server:

Server version: Apache/2.2.3
PHP Version 5.3.19
MySQL version 5.5.28
Drupal 6.19
Centos 5.8

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set AllowOwerride in your vhosts config? Try to type some nonsense string in your .htaccess file and check log file. If there is no errors, that means your Apache doesnt use .htaccess config.

Answer (score 1):

check to make sure that AllowOverride is not set to none for the Directory that drupal resides in.

Answer (score 0):

Does `RewriteEngine On` appear in your Apache configuration or `.htaccess` file? Since you’re using `.htaccess` for the rewrites, you’ll probably need a [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive, too.